# GraphDB - Inferred statements from new empty repository

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, rdfs, graphdb

I'm running some basic tests with GraphDB, and I am surprised to see that when a new repository is created, some statements seems to already be there (inferred by GraphDB).

Here is the summary of the repository that tells about those statements:

[image]

And the result of a sparql query to list them `CONSTRUCT {?s ?p ?o} WHERE {?s ?p ?o .} LIMIT 100`

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix sesame: <http://www.openrdf.org/schema/sesame#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix fn: <http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#> .

rdf:type a rdf:Property;
  rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:type;
  <http://proton.semanticweb.org/protonsys#transitiveOver> rdfs:subClassOf .

rdfs:subPropertyOf a rdf:Property, owl:TransitiveProperty;
  rdfs:subPropertyOf rdfs:subPropertyOf;
  <http://proton.semanticweb.org/protonsys#transitiveOver> rdfs:subPropertyOf .

rdfs:subClassOf a rdf:Property, owl:TransitiveProperty;
  rdfs:subPropertyOf rdfs:subClassOf;
  rdfs:domain rdfs:Class;
  rdfs:range rdfs:Class;
  <http://proton.semanticweb.org/protonsys#transitiveOver> rdfs:subClassOf .

rdfs:domain a rdf:Property;
  rdfs:subPropertyOf rdfs:domain;
  rdfs:range rdfs:Class .

rdfs:range a rdf:Property;
  rdfs:subPropertyOf rdfs:range;
  rdfs:range rdfs:Class .

owl:equivalentProperty a owl:SymmetricProperty, owl:TransitiveProperty;
  rdfs:subPropertyOf rdfs:subPropertyOf;
  <http://proton.semanticweb.org/protonsys#transitiveOver> owl:equivalentProperty;
  owl:inverseOf owl:equivalentProperty .

owl:equivalentClass a owl:SymmetricProperty, owl:TransitiveProperty;
  rdfs:subPropertyOf rdfs:subClassOf;
  <http://proton.semanticweb.org/protonsys#transitiveOver> owl:equivalentClass;
  owl:inverseOf owl:equivalentClass .

<http://proton.semanticweb.org/protonsys#transitiveOver> a rdf:Property;
  rdfs:subPropertyOf <http://proton.semanticweb.org/protonsys#transitiveOver> .

owl:inverseOf a rdf:Property, owl:SymmetricProperty;
  rdfs:subPropertyOf owl:inverseOf;
  owl:inverseOf owl:inverseOf .

rdf:subject a rdf:Property;
  rdfs:domain rdf:Statement .

rdf:predicate a rdf:Property;
  rdfs:domain rdf:Statement .

rdf:object a rdf:Property;
  rdfs:domain rdf:Statement .

rdf:first a rdf:Property;
  rdfs:domain rdf:List .

rdf:rest a rdf:Property;
  rdfs:domain rdf:List;
  rdfs:range rdf:List .

rdf:value a rdf:Property .

rdf:nil a rdf:List .

rdf:XMLLiteral a rdfs:Class, rdfs:Datatype;
  rdfs:subClassOf rdfs:Literal, rdf:XMLLiteral .

owl:differentFrom a owl:SymmetricProperty;
  owl:inverseOf owl:differentFrom .

xsd:nonNegativeInteger a rdfs:Class, rdfs:Datatype;
  rdfs:subClassOf xsd:nonNegativeInteger .

xsd:string a rdfs:Class, rdfs:Datatype;
  rdfs:subClassOf xsd:string .

rdf:_1 a rdf:Property, rdfs:ContainerMembershipProperty .

rdfs:isDefinedBy rdfs:subPropertyOf rdfs:seeAlso .

rdf:Alt rdfs:subClassOf rdfs:Container .

rdf:Bag rdfs:subClassOf rdfs:Container .

rdf:Seq rdfs:subClassOf rdfs:Container .

rdfs:ContainerMembershipProperty rdfs:subClassOf rdf:Property .

rdfs:Datatype rdfs:subClassOf rdfs:Class .

rdfs:comment rdfs:range rdfs:Literal .

rdfs:label rdfs:range rdfs:Literal .
```

They seem to reflect a partial description of the rdf, rdfs and owl vocabulary, but also include some properties from `http://proton.semanticweb.org/protonsys#`. I tried to figure out what they are and especially why they are present by default in a GraphDB repository, but I haven't found such information in GraphDb documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a guess, but from the docs it looks like they use Proton for rule optimization: https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/8.4/free/rules-optimisations.html

Comment: These are the axiomatic statements (and what is derived from these) defined in the ruleset you choose when the repository was created ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned 70 triples are the axiomatic triples part of the selected default RDFS Plus (Optimized) ruleset during the repository instantiation. The purpose of these non-deletable statements is to assert evident base assumptions like:

`<rdf:type> <rdf:type> <rdf:Property>` (every rdf:type relation is a property)

Their sole purpose is to ensure compliance with the [RDFS semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/). You can control them from the PIE files stored in `$GDB_HOME/configs/rules` directory. For further information, you can check the software documentation:

https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/reasoning.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure his question was about the triples with Proton ontology predicates, like `<http://proton.semanticweb.org/protonsys#transitiveOver>` - those are clearly not part of any standard so it's not standard conformant with RDF, RDFS, etc. if those are also returned. But as I said in my comment, most likely you make use of those triples for rule optimizations? And you call it RDFS Plus, so there is no standard for it anyways ...

Comment: Yes, it is used to implement a more generic transitivity so to reduce the number of rules. It is discussed in GraphDB documentation at https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/rules-optimisations.html#consider-specialized-property-constructs